# jQuery change only a portion of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string inside an input file.

```
<input type="file" data-url="/modules/wizard/upload.php?eid=18000115&amp;type=ico&amp;case=protagonist&amp;id=121001118" value="" class="wizard_image" name="files">


data-url="/modules/wizard/upload.php?eid=18000115&amp;type=ico&amp;case=protagonist&amp;id=121001118"
```

Now of this string I only want to change the very last param: `id=121001118` with something different and not the entire value of the `data-url` attribute.

How can I do it? The below one will change the entire string that is not what I am looking for.

```
newBox.find('input.wizard_image').attr('data-url', 'somethingElse');
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried using Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
newBox.find('input.wizard_image').attr('data-url', function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/id=\d+$/, 'id=somethingElse');
});
```

[Passing a function to `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) makes it easy to modify the existing value.

Explanation of the expression:

```
id= // literally matches "id="
\d+ // matches one or more digits 
$   // matches the end of the line/string
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use string functions: `substring`, `replace`.

```
var str = 'data-url="/modules/wizard/upload.php?eid=18000115&amp;type=ico&amp;case=protagonist&amp;id=121001118"';

var id = str.substring(str.indexOf(";id=") + 4);

str = str.replace(id, "something...");
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbfbX/)

But, a better solution is using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newID = 123435465;                       // the new Id you'd like to put into the URL
var $el = newBox.find('input.wizard_image'); // take the reference of the element
var oldURL = $el.data('url');                // get the data-url
var newURL = oldURL.replace(/id=[0-9]+/, newID);// replace the id=number pattern by newID
$el.data('url', newURL);                        // set it to a new one by replacing
```

Comment: Its a good idea to put some description with an answer, rather than just a block of new text.

Comment: The code is very well commented, and the comments serves perfectly well as description, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way using Regular expresion

```
newBox.find('input.wizard_image').attr('data-url', 
        newBox.find('input.wizard_image').replace(/id\=[0-9]{0,}/gi, "something-else")
);
```